# how to delete kafka message after reading

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I am using the below code to read messages from a topic. How do i delete a message after it is read?

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer


    consumer = KafkaConsumer('my-topic',
                             group_id='my-group',
                             bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
    for message in consumer:
        # message value and key are raw bytes -- decode if necessary!
        # e.g., for unicode: `message.value.decode('utf-8')`
        print ("%s:%d:%d: key=%s value=%s" % (message.topic, message.partition,
                                              message.offset, message.key,
                                              message.value))
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586008/delete-message-after-consuming-it-in-kafka

Answer (score 9):

There is no way to delete a specific message from kafka - kafka simply is not designed to do that. The only way to delete messages is by setting `log.retention.hours` in kafka's `config/server.properties` to a value of your liking. The default is 168 - meaning that messages are not kept after 168 hours.

If you instead are looking for a way to read messages from a specific offset - i.e. not read from the beginning every time, look here http://kafka-python.readthedocs.org/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html
`commit()` - committing read offsets to kafka
`seek_to_end()` - fast forward to consuming only newly arriving messages
`seek()` - moving to a given offset (presumably stored somewhere else than in kafka)