# Deleting Kafka messages after consumers' receipt

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In my kafka java-project I want to delete the messages as soon as all interested consumers have received the new message. After some research I have found some old stackoverflow questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694191/how-to-delete-kafka-message-after-reading), [one more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52961751/how-to-delete-data-which-already-been-consumed-by-consumer-kafka) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586008/delete-message-after-consuming-it-in-kafka). After reading all these, I've got some questions.

As far as i could understand, I really should rely on retention either by time or by space. However, the answers are old so maybe something changed? Is there any other way to really ensure that messages are deleted right after all the currently connected consumers have read the message? In this case I would need to check whether or not all consumers have read the message. Would I need a consumer-group for that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to delete messages after consuming it? is it to avoid duplicate message delivery or any other reason?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Kafka is designed to be a distributed commit log. The behaviour you want is a publish-subscribe system, like a JMS server, RabbitMQ or maybe amazon SNS.

Comment: @GoviS   The thing is, that I need the consumers to really process the message. So I want to delete the message once all consumers have actually received and processed it. Currently the processing time as well as the message-size can vary like a lot so i really cannot put time or size constraints as for retention.

Comment: @GreyFairer the answer above

Comment: I can let consumers commit after processing, but would that help me?

Comment: Just to know if consumers have processed all messages, they need to commit what they consumed, and you can check their offsets.

Comment: @GreyFairer So theoretically I could let the adminClient delete the message once all consumers commited?

Comment: @AksimElnik theoretically, yes, but it's not necessary, as the answer below points out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need worry about when the messages will be deleted or compacted **to achieve your goal**

As far as your consumer is concerned, if the consumers commit the offset of every message they consumed, those processed messages, regardless of how long they will stay in the topic, are dead in the view of your consumers.

Note:

An administrative user can go and reset your consumer to read gain from the beginning including those messages your consumers moved on from. But that is a manual admin operation.

Comment: Maybe interesting to add:

If you deploy a new consumer with a new consumer group, you can also choose to either start with offset 0, to receive old messages again, or start from the current offset, and only receive new messages.