# Delete a specific kafka message

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to instruct kafka to remove a message whenever possible. If using keys and log compaction it can be done setting the key to the message ID and the message content to null. But I look for something more direct that does not depend on setting the key such as through the message id.

Comment: Kafka is not made to delete messages. I is a rolling log, and messages are automagicly deleted after a ttl. If you feel the need to delete messages it is not the correct datastore for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586008/delete-message-after-consuming-it-in-kafka