# delete kafka logs for consumed messages, using SCS

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Am new in using kafka and spring cloud stream. Need some help.

**SetUP**

- I have two spring-boot applications **App-1, App-2**.
- I am using **spring cloud stream** and **spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka** for async communication.
- There is one topic **TOPIC-1**

---

**Use Case**

- Suppose App-1 sent a message on topic TOPIC-1 which App-2 was listening.
- App-2 consumed the message and processed it successfully.
- Now offset of that topic gets incremented.

  ---

## Question

- *How can i implement a mechanism to delete the only successfully consumed message's data from kafka logs after a specified period of time?*

In Kafka, the responsibility of what has been consumed is the responsibility of the consumer. So I guess, there must be some kafka message log control mechanism in **spring cloud stream kafka** that i am not aware of.

---

NOTE 1 : I know about the kafka log retention time and disk properties. But kafka logs will be deleted even for non consumed messages.

NOTE 2: I have gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586008/delete-message-after-consuming-it-in-kafka) but it can't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>There is no such mechanism, that I am aware of, in Kafka; and certainly not in Spring Cloud Stream or the libraries it is based on. Kafka clients don't have access to such low-level constructs.</s>

Also, consumer offsets are completely separate to the topic logs; in modern brokers, they are stored in a special topic.

**EDIT**

Per the comment below, the `kafka-delete-records.sh` command line tool can be used.

Note that this uses the scala `AdminClient` which is not on the SCSt classpath by default (since 2.0).

However, the java `AdminClient` supports similar functionality:

```
/**
 * Delete records whose offset is smaller than the given offset of the corresponding partition.
 *
 * This is a convenience method for {@link #deleteRecords(Map, DeleteRecordsOptions)} with default options.
 * See the overload for more details.
 *
 * This operation is supported by brokers with version 0.11.0.0 or higher.
 *
 * @param recordsToDelete       The topic partitions and related offsets from which records deletion starts.
 * @return                      The DeleteRecordsResult.
 */
public DeleteRecordsResult deleteRecords(Map<TopicPartition, RecordsToDelete> recordsToDelete) {
    return deleteRecords(recordsToDelete, new DeleteRecordsOptions());
}
```

You can create an `AdminClient` using boot's `AutoConfiguration` `KafkaAdmin`.

```
AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(kafkaAdmin.getConfig());
```

Comment: Thanks Russell:)) Maybe we can use `kafka-delete-records.sh` to schedule a delete job till the offset. I guess it would be safe to delete as messages till offset is processed successfully, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks Russell for your answer.